# Understanding some xpath expression

Tags: xslt, xpath

Could someone help me decrypt this xpath expression?

```
<xsl:template match="n1:table/@* | 
                     n1:thead/@* | 
                     n1:tfoot/@* | 
                     n1:tbody/@* | 
                     n1:colgroup/@* | 
                     n1:col/@* | 
                     n1:tr/@* | 
                     n1:th/@* | 
                     n1:td/@*">
```

I believe it's somewhere around:

Select all attributes from n1:table element AND all attributes from n1:thead element AND all attributes from n1:tfoot ... etc.

I'm really not sure though.

Was reading this to get understand the xpath:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Care to give me a hint?

Thx.

Comment: One more hint: don't use w3schools as a tutorial. Please read [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: So what should I use, w3 official recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've basically got it right. The `|` is the XPath' union set operator:

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets

> The `|` operator computes the union of
>   its operands, which must be node-sets

But in patterns, from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#patterns

> In a pattern, | indicates
>   alternatives; a pattern with one or
>   more | separated alternatives matches
>   if any one of the alternative matches.

So the template matches for any attributes of table, thead, tbody, etc in the namespace referenced by `n1` relative to the current context node.

You'll also need to account for the presence of a namespace in your source document using something like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
     version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:n1="uri:something">
```

More on namespaces in XSLT templates:

http://radio-weblogs.com/0118231/stories/2006/10/03/xslt10PatternMatchingTipsForSourceDocumentsWithNamespaces.html

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, I've been crash coursing xslt/xpath for a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually an XPath expression - it's an XSLT pattern. The syntax of patterns is a subset of the syntax of expressions, so they are closely related, but the semantics works rather differently. In particular, whereas an XPath expression selects nodes, a pattern matches them (or doesn't, as the case may be).

Anyway, a node matches the pattern P|Q if it matches either P or Q or both, and a node matches X/@* if it is an attribute of an element named X, and that basically explains this pattern.